# Code Igniter Generating Query Result

Tags: codeigniter, view

I'm having trouble generating my query result.

```
$query = $this->db->query("YOUR QUERY");

foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
{
   echo $row['title'];
   echo $row['name'];
   echo $row['body'];
}
```

Will this work?

```
$query = $this->db->query("YOUR QUERY");

foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
{
   echo $row['0'];
   echo $row['1'];
   echo $row['2'];
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Edward mentioned, the array returned is an associative array. While there is no standard way to index into assoc array using integers, you could do it this way:

```
$resultarray = $query->result_array();
// get an array of keys in result
$keys = array_keys($resultarray[0]);

foreach ($resultarray as $row)
{
   echo $row[$keys[0]];
   echo $row[$keys[1]];
   echo $row[$keys[2]];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

$query->result_array() generates an associative array. You can't access it's elements by index.